# SignalR 1.1.3 count online users\connections, exceptions and sometimes doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Basically it works but sometimes these exceptions occur (always on *OnReconnected*):

> 1. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> 2. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

i think to know which is the problem (like when you try to add an item in a foreach to the same list), but what can i do to solve this?

Code:

```
public class UsersHub : Hub
{
    private struct SignalRUser
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    static IList<SignalRUser> users = new List<SignalRUser>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        this.AddUser();

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        this.RemoveUser();

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        this.AddUser();

        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    private string GetClientId()
    {
        string clientId = "";
        if (!(Context.QueryString["clientId"] == null))
        {
            clientId = Context.QueryString["clientId"].ToString();
        }

        if (clientId.Trim() == "")
        { 
            clientId = Context.ConnectionId;
        }

        return clientId;
    }

    private void AddUser()
    {
        var user = Membership.GetUser();
        string clientId = GetClientId();

        if (!users.Any(x => x.ClientId == clientId))
        {
            users.Add(new SignalRUser
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Username = user.UserName                   
            });
        }
    }

    private void RemoveUser()
    {
        string clientId = GetClientId();
        users.Remove(users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved using "lock(users)" to prevent that different threads can modify users at the same time.

example:

```
private void RemoveUser()
{
    string clientId = GetClientId();
    lock(users)
    {
        users.Remove(users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId));
    }
}
```